# What does "it" refer to in this paragraph about creativity?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A good many scientists and artists have noticed the  universality of creativity. At the Sixteenth Nobel Conference, held in 1980, scientists, musicians, and philosophers all agreed, to quote Freeman Dyson, that “the analogies between science and art are very good as long as you are talking about the creation and the performance. The creation is certainly very analogous. The aesthetic pleasure of the craftsmanship of performance is also very strong in science.” A few years later, at another multidisciplinary conference, physicist Murray Gell-Mann found that “everybody agrees on **where ideas come from**. We had a seminar here, about ten years ago, including several painters, a poet, a couple of writers, and the physicists. Everybody agrees on how **it** works. All of these people, whether they are doing artistic work or scientific work, are trying to solve a problem.”

What does **it** refer to here?
it refers to the phrase **where ideas come from**? To me, it seems so obscure

Comment: Surely it means **creativity**, the topic of the paragraph, so "how creativity works."

Comment: Thanks so much! i totally understand now